# RapidXML weird output

Tags: c++, qt, file, rapidxml

I'm currently trying to use RapidXML to write a file out, this is the code I've got for it

```
    xml_document<> doc;
    xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
    doc.append_node(decl);
    xml_node<> *root = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "config");
    for(int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
        bool LineEdit = false;
        std::pair<QLabel*, QLineEdit*> LabelAndLine;
        LabelAndLine.first = ui->centralwidget->findChild<QLabel*>(params.at(i).first);
        if (LabelAndLine.first == nullptr) {
            LineEdit = true;
            LabelAndLine.second = ui->centralwidget->findChild<QLineEdit*>(params.at(i).first);
        }
        QString nodename = params.at(i).second;
        qInfo() << "Setting: "+nodename+" from "+params.at(i).first;
        xml_node<> *param = doc.allocate_node(node_element, QStringToConstCharPoint(nodename));
        xml_attribute<char> *value;
        if (LineEdit) {
            value = doc.allocate_attribute("value", QStringToConstCharPoint(LabelAndLine.second->text()));
        }
        else {
            value = doc.allocate_attribute("value", QStringToConstCharPoint(LabelAndLine.first->text()));
        }
        param->append_attribute(value);
        root->append_node(param);
    }
    doc.append_node(root);
    std::string xmlName = std::to_string(time(NULL))+".xml";
    std::ofstream fileStored(xmlName);
    fileStored << doc;
    fileStored.close();
    doc.clear();
```

It reads a value from Qt (either a QLabel or a QLineEdit) then compares it to a vector of pairs (const QString, const QString) defined here:

```
std::vector<std::pair<const QString,const QString>> params = {{"PopulationInput","population"},
                                                          {"XInput","AreaX"},
                                                          {"YInput","AreaY"},
                                                          {"AlreadyInfectedInput","AlreadyInfected"},
                                                          {"InfectionProbabilityIndicator","infectProbability"},
                                                          {"RadOfInfectionInput","infectionRadius"},
                                                          {"CPUThreadsDisplay","threads"},
                                                         };
```

but when I look at the output file it just shows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<co value='ding="utf-8"'/>
    <ding="utf-8" value='ding="utf-8"'/>
    <ding="utf-8" value='ding="utf-8"'/>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<co value='ding="utf-8"'/>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<co value='ding="utf-8"'/>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<co value='ding="utf-8"'/>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <ding="utf-8"?>
<co value='ding="utf-8"'/>
</config>
```

The QStringToConstCharPoint function is defined as this:

```
const char* QStringToConstCharPoint(QString input) {
    QByteArray ba = input.toLocal8Bit();
    const char *result = ba.data();
    return result;
}
```

Why is my output looking like that? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the QStringToConstCharPoint function was the issue, it was messing something up with RapidXML and I don't know why, but I found a better way to do it.